# What is the default name of embedded H2 database in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, h2

As I've read the default name of the embedded H2 database in Spring Boot should be `testdb`, but if I try to connect to with the H2 Console, I get the following error:

> Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments)

It works only if I set the name explicitly in the `application.properties` with the following parameter:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Since the application can connect to the embedded database without this configuration, there must be a different default name. **But what is the default name of the automatically configured database?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable h2 console in application.properties as jurez said

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

and then when you run the application in the console you will see something like this:

```
H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:2f5b7da9-0cd2-4fdd-98d2-5ef5f76391bc'
```

then you can use this JDBC URL to connect to the database from the h2-console

```
http://localhost:8080/h2-console

jdbc:h2:mem:2f5b7da9-0cd2-4fdd-98d2-5ef5f76391bc
```

you can specify your own name by adding the following property in the application.property file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

remember since this is an in-memory database it will be dropped and recreated every time you run your application

h2 also has a persistent mode but it is not recommended, you can do that by adding the following configurations taken from the following tutorial [Spring Boot and H2 in memory database - Why, What and How?](https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-h2-in-memory-database)

```
spring.datasource.name=yourdbname
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
 
spring.datasource.initialize=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/yourdbname;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;IFEXISTS=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;
 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, memory databases are only accessible to the process in which they are running.

If you want to access it from H2 Console, you need to enable it in application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the problem. H2 is accessible from the H2 Console, since it runs in the same process. It works, if I set the database name explicitly, but there must be a default name (I don't know).

Comment: Not necessary. A name is only needed when an endpoint provides several databases (such as standalone server) and the endpoint must know which database you are referring to. In case of embedded server (`mem:`), a database is simply a Java object - it needs neither a name, nor an endpoint, nor a password. This would be preferred from security point of view, too.